# Android onStop times out despite doing no work

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-anr-dialog

I'm having trouble with an app crashing when returning to the activity.

If I navigate away with the home button the phone (or emulator) onPause, onSaveInstanceState, and onStop are all called as per the lifecycle:

```
05-05 14:12:20.790 2043-2043/? I/myview: onPause was run
05-05 14:12:20.790 2043-2043/? I/myview: onSaveInstanceState was run
05-05 14:12:20.790 2043-2043/? I/myview: onStop was run
```

Code in the activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("myview", "onPause was run");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("myview", "onStop was run");
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("myview", "onSaveInstanceState was run");
    }
```

However after ten seconds the following is reported:

```
05-05 14:12:31.420 1586-1601/? W/ActivityManager: Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{9d354dc0 u0 com.example.gavin.youdrowned/.MainActivity t2}
05-05 14:12:31.420 1586-1601/? I/ActivityManager: Activity reported stop, but no longer stopping: ActivityRecord{9d354dc0 u0 com.example.gavin.youdrowned/.MainActivity t2}
```

I'm able to navigate back to the activity, but onResume or onCreate are not called.

The app runs full screen as expected until I try to interact with it. Tap/Clicking on the screen causes the following error to occur after about 5 seconds or so:

```
05-05 14:12:31.420 1586-1601/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.example.gavin.youdrowned (com.example.gavin.youdrowned/.MainActivity)
                                                  PID: 2043
                                                  Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.)
                                                  Load: 0.54 / 0.13 / 0.04
                                                  CPU usage from 2796ms to -2455ms ago:
                                                    86% 2043/com.example.gavin.youdrowned: 11% user + 74% kernel / faults: 193 minor 1 major
                                                    49% 1586/system_server: 0.1% user + 48% kernel / faults: 874 minor
                                                    2% 1162/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 2% kernel / faults: 7 minor
                                                    0.1% 1160/debuggerd: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 3473 minor 12 major
                                                    0.3% 1165/mediaserver: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 15 minor
                                                    0.3% 1173/adbd: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 216 minor
                                                    0.3% 1938/com.google.android.gms: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 62 minor
                                                    0.1% 1186/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                    0.1% 1708/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 22 minor
                                                    0.1% 1746/com.android.phone: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 98 minor
                                                   +0% 2373/com.google.android.gms.ui: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                  71% TOTAL: 7.8% user + 63% kernel
                                                  CPU usage from 1945ms to 2451ms later:
                                                    98% 1586/system_server: 0% user + 98% kernel / faults: 1 minor
                                                      96% 1622/Thread-35: 0% user + 96% kernel
                                                      1.9% 1601/ActivityManager: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
                                                    98% 2043/com.example.gavin.youdrowned: 12% user + 86% kernel / faults: 4 minor
                                                      98% 2088/Thread-62: 12% user + 86% kernel
                                                     +0% 2401/AudioTrack: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                    1.6% 1162/surfaceflinger: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
                                                  100% TOTAL: 6% user + 94% kernel
```

The onResume never being called and the onStop timeout seems to indicate the ANR error on the back of the touch event isn't the main issue, however the onStop does no work other than a log to say it was called.

I'm not sure what's causing this issue or where to look to debug it and any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you acquired any resources that you are obligated to release, but do not perform that?

Comment: The only thing I could think of is SoundPool but releasing that has had no effect on the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After months of on-off power guessing changing:

```
holder.getSurface().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

to

```
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

In the code that manages screen updates seems to have fixed this problem.

Comment: Hi @Gavin, can you elaborate this I'm facing a very very similar issue and it's driving me insane.

Comment: Hi @EmilBorconi. 

I must confess I found the above fix by changing things line by line until it worked. I'd misused unlockCanvasAndPost after following guides I didn't well understand. The stack trace didn't really help at all and updating the canvas didn't seem to be an issue even.

A lot of issues I had were caused by following guides that didn't mention the Android version it was written for.

I was testing on a KitKat AVD (API Level: 19) as that's the hardware I had available at the time which was very outdated even then, but the code I'd learned was not compatible.

Comment: Thanks @Gavin. My issue was similar but not quite the same. My problem was that the onSurfaceDestory didn't get called, when the app was put in background. Thanks for getting back to me though.